# Best practice for further actions in rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, restful-architecture

i'm just writing my first app in rails and i wonder, if there is a best practice to do the following:

i have a customer model created by a scaffold and pumping it up. a customer has to be displayed in a google map, so if go to /customers/23, the customer information are displayed. additionally i have a link within this page to show the user in a map (with a query ui dialog that comes up via ajax).
The question for me is, how does this fits in the normal crud structure of the model. Should i do like creating an action, called "show_map" and give it an extra route additionally to the resources routes? How do you handle this kind of things?

Comment: There are varying opinionated answers on this (it's not so much a Rails question as a REST question); as such, I don't think StackOverflow is a good fit for your question. I'd try programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: hi, thanks, i didn't know about this part of stackexchange.com, so perhaps i'm going to try it, although i'm not really sure, if the question is general enough for it... thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets do it like

```
resources :customers do
 resource :map, :only => [:index]
end
```

it will generate routes like this

```
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"maps"}     customer_map GET      /customers/:customer_id/map(.:format)
```

Comment: ok, i agree, but is this map functionality a real "resource"? my first opinion was like to get declare a member of the recource customer: get 'show_map'...

Comment: yes 'map' is a real resource with only show method if you want all methods, remove ":only => [:index]" part